# Xamarin Forms Increase Hit Area of Image

Tags: xamarin, win-universal-app, xamarin.forms, uitapgesturerecognizer, uwp-xaml

I'm working on a `Xamarin.Forms` application in which I'm using an image as clickable icon to close a popup.  I've made the image clickable via `TapGestureRecognizer` as shown below:

```xml
<Image Source="x-icon.png" HeightRequest="15" WidthRequest="15">
  <Image.GestureRecognizers>
    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OnClosePopupTapped"/>
  </Image.GestureRecognizers>
</Image>
```

The `OnClosePopupTapped` function in my `xaml.cs` is being hit correctly.

My problem is that only the top left corner of the image triggers the function (**the hit area of the image is not the full image**).

Does anyone know of a solution to increase the hit area to the full image instead of just the top left corner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easy way to achieve a larger hit box would be to wrap your image in another control, like a `<StackLayout>` or a `<Frame>`with an appropriate padding applied to the parent. Then, apply your gesture recognizer to the parent and set your image to be InputTransparent

Should look something like this:

```
  <Frame Padding="10">
    <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
      <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OnClosePopupTapped"/>
    </Frame.GestureRecognizers>

    <Image Source="x-icon.png" HeightRequest="15" WidthRequest="15" InputTransparent="True"/>
  </Frame>
```

[InputTransparent](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.InputTransparent/) when set to true will pass the input to the element below, which in this case is the Frame

Also, I have not tried it personally yet, but I think the latest Xamarin.Forms supports image buttons, which might be a simple solution as well:

```
<Button Image="x-icon.png" Command="OnClosePopopCommand"/>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer :D as an fyi to people who might come across this solution in the future: for me `InputTransparent` didnt work, but i took that part out and it did.